# Difference MediaWiki system messages Nocreatetext, Noarticletext, Noarticletext-nopermission, Newarticle and Newarticletext

Tags: mediawiki

[Manual:Interface/Noarticletext](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Interface/Noarticletext)
 defines the pages that are shown for non existing pages.

But what about MediaWiki:Nocreatetext, MediaWiki:Newarticle and MediaWiki:Newarticletext? Are these messages outdated or do they provide extra functionality?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`noarticletext` is the text that is shown when viewing a non-existent page.

`noarticletext-nopermission` is shown instead of the above if the user doesn't have the rights to create the page (it hides the edit link in the message)

`nocreatetext` is shown to logged out users when they try to **edit** a non-existent page and don't have permission to do so. For logged in users it will use `nocreate-loggedin` instead.

`newarticle` was used on Special:Contributions to mark new pages. No longer in use since 1.16 from what I can see.

`newarticletext` is shown above the editor when editing a non-existent page (assuming they can edit).

The rights that determine if a user can create a page are `edit`, `createpage` and `createtalk`. The `(all)` group has all these rights by default. You can view the groups and their rights with `Special:ListGroupRights`

Comment: Thank a lot. Do you have a reference to documentation about this?

Comment: I couldn't find any documentation about this, no. I first looked through the source code where the messages were used and then was able to replicate them. You can use the `qqx` lang (`?uselang=qqx`) to see all messages on a page.

Comment: Wow! Nice! (that uselang=qqx)

Comment: Try https://translatewiki.net/wiki/MediaWiki:Noarticletext/qqq for documentation.